# Laravel Eloquent - OneToOne

Tags: laravel, eloquent, one-to-one, relation

I have a WorkOrder model which has a supplier_id field which needs to relate to a supplier (suppliers are in the contacts table in my database). I have a 'supplier' method on my WorkOrder model which is intended to retrieve the supplier but appears to be returning Null. What am I missing:

```
class WorkOrder extends Model
{
    //

    public function supplier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class, 'supplier_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

So 'id' is the primary key on the Contacts table, 'supplier_id' is the field in the WorkOrder table to hold the relation to the supplier (contact).

So in my controller I get my WorkOrders collection with:

```
$workOrders = WorkOrder::with('supplier')->get();
```

This correctly returns a collection of WorkOrders however in the relations I have supplier = Null:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1613 ▼
  #items: array:11 [▼
    0 => App\Models\WorkOrder {#1655 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "work_orders"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:18 [▶]
      #original: array:18 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #classCastCache: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "supplier" => null
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
```

Comment: is there a relationship existing in the database at the moment?

Comment: Yes I have added 11 test WorkOrders each have the same value in the supplier_id column and this is a valid Contact who has that ID

Comment: Oh dear... School boy error. Thanks @lagbox you got me thinking to check the validity of the relation. I have a global scope constraint on my contact model which I had forgotten about.